# What is the difference between "Listen my voice" to "Listen to my voice"?

Tags: complementation, transitivity

What is the difference between

> "Listen my voice"

to

> "Listen **to** my voice"?

Comment: The first one is incorrect, and the second one is correct.  You don't "listen something", you "listen TO something".

Comment: Thank you! By the way, can I say "Hear my voice"?

Comment: Yes, because "hear" doesn't require a preposition, so you can say "They hear my voice" or "Hear my voice!"

Comment: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/listen_1?q=listen

Comment: Related question at ELU: **[Why is “listen” always followed by “to” in the command voice?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12897/why-is-listen-always-followed-by-to-in-the-command-voice)**, and another: **[Intransitive verbs with preposition in passive sentences](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193000/intransitive-verbs-with-preposition-in-passive-sentences)** and another: **[Why Listen to Music, why not Listening Music](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15486/why-listen-to-music-why-not-listening-music)**

Comment: *Listen* is intransitive and never takes an object.  Instead, it takes preposition phrases headed by *to*.

Comment: @snailboat - John Lawler [here argues that it is transitive](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/193033/48335)

Comment: Ah, the joy of multiple incompatible theoretical frameworks!

Answer (score 5):

When the verb doesn't have an object, you can omit the preposition *to*.

> *People never listen.*

In your example, you have to use *listen **to**.*

Comment: May you please show an example of a verb with object and without?

Comment: @Assiduous With object: "Listen to my voice". Without: "People never listen". Also with: "People never listen to my voice".

Comment: Thanks to you, I think that I got it. Thank you for the help